# Proof equivalent statements of $D \subset X$ is dense in $X$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I need to prove that the following statements are equivalent:

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}$.

(i) $D \subset X$ is dense in $X$.

(ii) Every point in $X \setminus D$ is a limit point of $D$.

(iii) For all closed subsets $A \subset \mathbb{R}$: if $D \subset A$ then $X \subset A$.

Our definitions of density and limit points are:

$D \subset X$ is dense in $X \iff $ for all open sets $O \subset \mathbb{R}$: if $O \cap X \neq \emptyset$ then $O \cap D \neq \emptyset$.

$x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of $D \subseteq \mathbb{R} \iff \forall \epsilon \gt 0 \exists d \in D: |d-x_0| \lt \epsilon$

I have tried proving i) -> ii) -> iii) -> i) but I can't get even one of them right. Can somebody help me out?

Comment: Are all your sets subsets of $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(i) $\implies$ (ii): Take $x\in X\setminus D$. For every $\varepsilon>0$, $\left(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon\right)$ is an open subset of $\mathbb R$. Furthermore $x\in\left(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon\right)\cap X$, and therefore $\left(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon\right)\cap X\neq\emptyset$. So there is some $d\in D$ such that $d\in\left(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon\right)\cap X$.

(ii) $\implies$ (iii): Let $A$ be a closed subset of $\mathbb R$ such that $D\subset A$. If $x\in X\setminus D$, then $x$ is a limit point of $D$ and therefore $x$ is the limit of some sequence of points of $D$. Since $A$ is closed, it follows from this that $x\in A$. So, this proves that $X\setminus D\subset A$. Since also $D\subset A$, $X\subset A$.

(iii) $\implies$ (i): Let $O$ be an open set and suppose that $O\cap X\neq\emptyset$ and that $O\cap D=\emptyset$. Then $D\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus O$. Since $\mathbb{R}\setminus O$ is a closed set, it follows that $X\subset\mathbb{R}\setminus O$. This is impossible, because $O\cap X\neq\emptyset$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have one question for (i):
How do you know that $d \in (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \cap X$? I understand only that because of $D$ being dense in $X$ that $d \in (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$. Is it important that $d$ is even in $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \cap X$? For the proof it should be enough that $d \in (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ if I understand correctly.

Comment: @philmcole Because $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ is an open set and $D$ is dense in $X$. Therefore $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap X$ contains some element of $D$.

Comment: Sorry to ask again but by the definition I know only that because $D$ is dense, for all open sets $O \subset \mathbb{R}$: if $O \cap X \neq \emptyset$ then $O \cap D \neq \emptyset$. So I take $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ as my open set, then because $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \cap X \neq \emptyset$ I know $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \cap D \neq \emptyset$. So there is a $d \in D: d \in (x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ but where do I know that this $d$ is even in $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon) \cap X$?

Comment: @philmcole This question is about which implication?

Comment: Still referring to my first comment, basically the last step in (i) $\implies$ (ii).

Comment: @philmcole SInce $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$ is an open set, $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)\cap D\neq\emptyset$. So I can take a $\in D$ which is also an element of $(x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon)$. But this means that $|d-x|<\varepsilon$.